# Could not find or load the main class after build

Tags: java, eclipse

My Java program works fine where I hit the button run or debug [image: run debug] in eclipse mars.

Actually I have a main class with main function

```
public class Main extends JFrame 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {...}
}
```

But when I build it I have the error "could not find or load the main class" (in french)
[image: command prompt]

Here is my run configuration:
[image: run config]

And I use it where I build the program to runable jar file (.jar) 
[image: build config]

EDIT 1:

After a comment I search how to create an automatic manifest file with eclipse, I create it but it doesn't solve the issue. Here is the content of the manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

My Main class is located in default package:

[image: main class location]

EDIT 2:

I've located the main class in a package named Launch.
I've extract the .jar file to see what's inside and the manifest file is here, the content is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Launch.Main
```

[image: manifest location]

Comment: You'll need a manifest if you don't want to explicitly name the class when running it with `java -jar xxx`

Comment: Where is that manifest in the final .jar, and why isn't your class in a package?

Answer (score 0):

The Class which includes your `main`-Method is simply called `Main` (as I assume from your code-snippet). You have to select this `Main` Class in the launch configuration when creating your .jar.

Currently you selected a Class called `Task_Card_Assembleur_Main`.

Comment: In fact this is the configuration name I've defined

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse right click the project > Export > Java > Jar File > Click on Next > Select your project > Browse the jar location to save > Next > Next > Select the class of the application entry point :{select class having main method 'Main'} > Click Finish